# 'First' in First-order logic

Tags: logic, terminology, first-order-logic

What does 'First' in First-order logic actually mean? It was never discussed when i was learning formal logic and was just used interchangeably with Predicate logic. I'm suspecting the terminology has mathematical relevance because of its usage in Second-order logic and higher-order logic.

Comment: The distinction is discussed in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_logic#Quantification_scope) on the subject.

Comment: Somebody more knowledgeable should post the answer. Hopefully, somebody who knows what they're talking about will read this comment and tell me how to correct any mistakes I may have made. I believe that in first-order logic you can quantify over the universe. In second-order logic you can quantify over subsets of the universe. In third-order logic you can quantify over subsets of subsets of the universe. Etc. Also since second-order logic allows you to quantify over subsets of the universe, you can make statements with phrases like "for all functions f" or "for all ternary predicates P".

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielV thank you for your help. If you imagine that the universe is $X$, then in first order logic you can quantify over elements of $X$. In second-order logic you can quantify over elements of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, the power set of $X$. In third-order logic you can quantify over elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$. Etc. This understates things a bit since in second-order logic you the fact that you can also quantify over elements $\mathcal{P}(X)$, means that you can also quantify over $n$-ary predicates, which are subsets of $X^n$, and $n$-ary functions, which are subsets of $X^{n+1}$.

Comment: I don't have a good conception of what sort of things you can do with third-order logic, that you couldn't do with second-order logic, so I was really hoping that someone more knowledgeable would post an answer. Another interesting question: is there a $\lambda$-order logic for any infinite ordinals $\lambda$?

Comment: @DanielV In second-order logic you can quantify over functions and predicates, and this does make second order logic many-sorted. You can learn more about second-order logic here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic